# How do I get Pandas (with numpy dependency) working on AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, aws-lambda

Background, AWS lambda functions won't recognize pandas in a venv zip file.

On a previous function I was able to use the following setup of layers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNhfT.png)

Pandas38 is a premade AWS layer I found that solved the Pandas package error
and AWSlamda scipy solved the numpy dependency (I'm only using pandas in my function)

but on my new lambda function I am running out of maximum allowed size when I try to use the same layers as last time, which is weird because I'm pretty confident my function zip file was still around the same size. Current zipped function size is 23,700kb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTwBQ.png)

I tried making a numpy layer with the wheels of numpy but that didn't work.